# FragmentManager pushing back button exits the app

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragmentmanager

Please refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34571946/slidingtablayout-pager-fragments-are-vanishing-after-parent-fragment-onpause-i) question for the setup of fragments:

```
|  A  |  B  |
         ↓
   |  C  |  D  |
      ↓
   |  E  |
```

I am struggling to figure out why my App is exiting on pressing the back button on a fragment added with addToBackStack().

According to the answer,

**Case 1:** If I use getSupportFragmentManager() or getFragmentManager(): my fragments vanish after I swipe to a different tab and come back.

**Case 2:** if I use getChildFragmentManager(): I dynamically add Fragment `E` to `C` while using `addToBackStack()` but when I press back, the app exits. Expectation is that it should return to `C` instead of exiting.

Code for adding tabs `C` and `D` is:

```
public class MyProfileTabFragmentPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
private String tabTitles[];
private Context context;
private String userID;

private static final String TAG = makeLogTag(MyProfileTabFragmentPagerAdapter.class);
public MyProfileTabFragmentPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, Context context) {
    super(fm);
    tabTitles = context.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.profileTabs);
    this.context = context;
    SharedPreferences prefs =
            PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);

    userID = prefs.getString("token", "");
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return tabTitles.length;
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    switch (position){
        case 0:
        {
            return UserProfileFragment.getInstance(userID);
        }
        case 1:
        {
            return new MySnapsFragment();
        }

        default:
        {
            LOGI(TAG, "Invalid tab" + position);
            return null;
        }
    }
}

@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
    // Generate title based on item position
    return tabTitles[position];
  }
}
```

This is how I setup my tabs in `B` which I call in its `onCreateView()`:

```
private void setupTabs() {
  // Get the ViewPager and set it's PagerAdapter so that it can display items
  vpProfileTab.setAdapter(new MyProfileTabFragmentPagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager(), ctx));

  // Give the TabLayout the ViewPager
  slidingProfileTabs.setDistributeEvenly(true);
  slidingProfileTabs.setBackgroundColor(colorAccent2);
  slidingProfileTabs.setSelectedIndicatorColors(colorTabIndicator);
  slidingProfileTabs.setViewPager(vpProfileTab);
}
```

I setup `C` from `B` using in `onCreateView()`:

```
    private void setupUserProfileFeed() {
    if(feedFragment==null){
        feedFragment = new FeedFragment();
        this.getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.feed_fragment, feedFragment).addToBackStack()
                .commit();
    }
}
```

I setup `E` from `C` when I click a button:

```
@Override
public void onProfileClick(View v) {
    UserProfileFragment userProfileFragment = UserProfileFragment.getInstance(userID);

    this.getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.feedContent, userProfileFragment)
            .addToBackStack(null).commit();
}
```

I am using SlidingTabLayout from Google github [here](https://github.com/google/iosched/blob/master/android/src/main/java/com/google/samples/apps/iosched/ui/widget/SlidingTabLayout.java).

I have the following questions:

1. What is the reason for **Case 1**. Which FM should be used, as per my understanding: getFM() should be used for top level and getChildFM() should be used for adding fragments to a fragment?
2. Why is the App exiting in **Case 2**? Do I need to do anything else?
3. How to solve this problem either way? Have been stuck for a while, any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Please show the code you are using, getChildFragmentManager() is used to get a FM that manages fragments within a fragment. You might use it in B to manage C & D.

getFragmentManager is used to manage fragments for an entire activity, if you are having fragments disappear while within the same activity it may be your usage of it.

Comment: I have added the tab setup code, please let me know if anything extra is needed.

Comment: Where is your addToBackStack call?

Comment: I added code for `B` -> `C` -> `E`. Thanks.

Comment: Child fragments do not get back button handling automatically, unfortunately. You'd have to delegate onBackPressed to the first level fragment, then have it recursively check if it or any child fragment has a back stack entry that needs to pop.

Comment: Yeah that seems to make sense. Also but why is **Case 1** working in the first place for first time with getFM() and why does it vanish?

Comment: @lionelmessi Not sure, unfortunately. Haven't really dealt with tab adapters, myself.

Answer (score 1):

override onBackPressed and make a switch statement for the different  view pager positions (0,1,2,3...) and tell it what to do in each case. Add this to the main activity where you are attaching the viewPager adapter. This example code is a simple way to do it if you want more complex behavior use the switch statement as previously described.

`@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (mViewPager.getCurrentItem() == 0) {
            // If the user is currently looking at the first page, allow android to handle the
            // Back button. This exits the app because you are on the first fragment.
            super.onBackPressed();
        } else {
            // Otherwise, select the fragment in the viewPager
            mViewPager.setCurrentItem(mViewPager.getCurrentItem() - 1);
        }
    }`

Comment: In which fragment do I need to do this or I need to do this in top level activity? Any sample usage would be helpful.

Comment: Well actually Case 2 seems a bug which Google wont fix!
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=&colspec=ID%20Status%20Priority%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars%20Reporter%20Opened&groupby=&sort=&id=40323